# Not able to create a data frame from Extracted text from Tesseract Ocr

Tags: python, pandas, tesseract

I have extracted the text from Image files using tesseract Ocr.  here is the sample image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRCEj.jpg)

From this image I have extracted the content and created a text file[Output file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1F3u.jpg)

Can someone help me, to extract this data in a Pandas data frame

Thanks!
Balaji

i tried importing all the lines into single column in a data frame. Here is the [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWN0U.png)

I want to create like a table as shown below

[Final table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec0or.png)